# How can I have the prefixes of a table name to be passed in via php as parameters in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to pass in a php variable as a parameter which will be the prefix of a table name within a MYSQL procedure which is called from my php code.

```
$result = mysql_query("CALL Order_Export_TempView('".$fromdate."','".$todate."');");
```

I already have managed to pass in some IN parameters $fromdate and $todate but when I try and do this for table names it doesnt seem to work. So far I havent attmepted passing in through php because I haven't had it work on the MYSQL dashboard.

So in the MYSQL procedure the table names will need to be as such: 
prefix_tablename

With prefix being my passed IN parameter from php.

Also, I cant place the entire query in my php code as it gives me a white screen due its massive size I believe, which is why I'm calling the procedure in the code and not inputting the entire query.

Comment: you shouldn't be using `mysql_` functions - they are deprecated and removed in php7

Comment: `it gives me a white screen due its massive size` That is doubtfull, unless it's like 100MB of text....  Probably you have a missing quote or something.

Comment: Thats what I thought as well, but I cant see it being syntax since the procedure runs fine in the MYSQL dashboard, but when Iv'e tried to put the same procedure in PHP it crashes...

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM `{$prefix}_lovely`"
```

But, as per the comments – do not use any `mysql_`, they are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).